Cannot do npm run
I have a ReactJS project, with package.json file:
{
  "name": "front-end",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "pg-promise": "^11.5.4",
    "querystring": "^0.2.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-resizable": "^3.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.16.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-split-pane": "^0.1.92",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "zlib": "^1.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "dev": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}


Whenever I do npm install it does not work therefore I add --force flag and I get:
npm error path C:\Users\MASTER\DatabaseViewerApp\front-end\node_modules\zlib
npm error command failed
npm error command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-waf clean || true; node-waf configure build
npm error System cannot find the path specified
npm error 'true' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
npm error operable program or batch file.
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\MASTER\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-09-26T18_02_42_496Z-debug-0.log

When I do npn run dev I can see that some libraries cannot be resolved:
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-router-dom' in 'C:\Users\MASTER\DatabaseViewerApp\front-end\src'
Even when I try to install this module with --force it still occurs.

Are you running npm install from correct folder? Can you share the screenshots?

https://pastebin.com/C7kb2Kjz
I run it in a folder with package.json

Ok, it seems like your react has some dependency conflict. Check if you can upgrade react-split-pane@0.1.92 or use an alternative that is more recent.

I get this:
C:\Users\MASTER\DatabaseViewerApp\front-end>npm upgrade react-split-pane
npm error code ERESOLVE
npm error ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm error
npm error While resolving: front-end@0.1.0
npm error Found: react@18.3.1
npm error node_modules/react
npm error   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error peer react@"^16.0.0-0" from react-split-pane@0.1.92
npm error node_modules/react-split-pane
npm error   react-split-pane@"^0.1.92" from the root project

Same problem, try npm install after removing react-split-pane and see if it works.

I get:
npm error command C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-waf clean || true; node-waf configure build
npm error System cannot find the path specified
npm error 'true' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

You're going to have to break this down to figure out what's not working.  There are a lot of things I can suggest, but the question is awfully broad the way it's phrased and there could be several things wrong.
Have you tried rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json and then npm install again?
If that doesn't work my next two questions are:

Did you write this code or did you download/generate it from somewhere else?

Has it ever worked or did it just suddenly stop working?



I wrote this code. It stopped working after I tried to install some module with force and then did ctrl + C, I removed and did npm install several times

Basically this pop up whenever I try do do something:
https://pastebin.com/c6QLEKx8

Seems like you answered your own question.  Good luck!

Basically removing of line:
    "zlib": "^1.0.5"
From "dependecies" in package.json solved a problem
